# How to do another calculation without exiting black screen?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Here is my code : a switch statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    float a,b,ans;
    int code;
    printf("enter two no\n");
    scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);

    printf("select an expression \n1-addition \n2-substraction \n3multiplication \n4-divide\n ");
    scanf("%d",&code);

switch(code)
{
    case 1:ans=a+b;
        printf("%f\n",ans);
    break;
    case 2:ans=a-b;
        printf("%f\n",ans);
    break;
    case 3:ans=a*b;
        printf("%f\n",ans);
    break;
    case 4:ans=a/b;
        printf("%f\n",ans);
    break;

}

getch();
}
```

Now after doing one calculation lets say 1-addition I want to again do another calculation without exiting the black screen. 
how it can be done?
if I have to put a loop then where and how, please explain.

Comment: Please read chapter two that is titled "while loops and what are you waiting for"

Comment: Yeah.. the thing is, you need to learn how to write programs.   That' I'm afraid, means actually working hard.   It often means reading books and looking stuff up, then trying stuff knowing it probably won't work right first time, then testing it, then debugging it and testing again.   That is how software engineering works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do the all operation for the given input till you choose to exit. But if you want to do the operation for different values the you can include the 7th and 8th line inside the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    float a,b,ans;
    int code;
    printf("enter two no\n");
    scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("select an expression \n1-addition \n2-substraction \n3multiplication \n4-divide \n5-Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&code);
        switch(code)
        {
            case 1:
                ans=a+b;
                printf("%f\n",ans);
                break;
            case 2:
                ans=a-b;
                printf("%f\n",ans);
                break;
            case 3:
                ans=a*b;
                printf("%f\n",ans);
                break;
            case 4:
                ans=a/b;
                printf("%f\n",ans);
                break;
        }

        if(code == 5)
        return;
 }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1){
printf("Press 0 to exit"); 
switch(code)
{
case 1:ans=a+b;
    printf("%f\n",ans);
break;
case 2:ans=a-b;
    printf("%f\n",ans);
break;
case 3:ans=a*b;
    printf("%f\n",ans);
break;
case 4:ans=a/b;
    printf("%f\n",ans);
case 0:
exit();


break;

}
}
```